# Angular/Typescript declared property links to service, but 'used before its initialization' error

Tags: angular, typescript

When I declare variables sometimes I link back to an Angular service.

Typescript throws this error: `"Property 'houseService' is used before its initialization."`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-overview',
  templateUrl: './map-overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-overview.component.sass'],
})
export class MapOverviewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  house$ = this.houseService.house$
  constructor(
    public houseService: HouseService,
  ) {
```

It worked before with es2020 and angular 14.

Now I moved over to es2022 and angular 16.

If I have the constructor before the properties it is fine, but that is a lot of code change and against some best (readability) practices.

Is there somehow I can suppress this error on `tsconfig.json` level?

Edit: Might have a wrong typscript version loaded in VS. After restart, these errors disappeared

Comment: Cannot reproduce in a fresh Angular 16 project. Please add more details about your project

Comment: Well there you say something interesting. Those migrations are always a pain. I restarted Visual Studio, and that error did disappear. I ll come back to this if I fixed all other errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new project shows that it works and I fixed it now in my migration. I think its a combi of:

- move up to `es2022`
- typescript `4.8` to `5.1`
- `useDefineForClassFields: false,` (was not there before in `tsconfig.json`)

Thanks @Cuzy for pointing in the right direction.

On a new project you can remove (not false) `useDefineForClassFields` and you end up with the same error

Comment: Angular forces `useDefineForClassField:false` and `target: 'es2022'` since v15.

Comment: FYI, it's `useDefineForClassFields` (plural). Source here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields

Answer (score 0):

Properties are initialized before the constructor. So when you declare

```
export class MapOverviewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  house$ = this.houseService.house$
  constructor(
    public houseService: HouseService,
  ) { }
```

`houseService` is undefined.

You need to move the definition of `house$` within the constructor:

```
  house$: House
  constructor(
    public houseService: HouseService,
  ) {
     this.house$ =  = this.houseService.house$
  }
```

Or if you use angular >=14, you can you the `inject()` function to define `houseService` before it's usage :

```
houseService = inject(HouseService)
house$ = this.houseService.house$
```

Comment: It did work before, in all my angular projects.  I am not so sure it is `undefined`.

Comment: @GeoDev It isn't, the resulting javascript assigns your property inside of the constructor anyway, so it doesn't matter if you use this or your version.

Comment: Check it before downvoting. This is definitely the issue. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCYCdoG8BQ0PWAewHYQBcEBXYA7BACgEoV1MGd9sQBTAOhGwHNKAiXKwDu0AEaI+1ehgC+qOalCQYAMWzY6DcUgC80QSPhVqAblTSseQiTIUamhpiYQWHLrwHDoa7JItyFA291GhMgA

Comment: I didnt downvote, appreciating your time. Altho as @Cuzy said, it is possible to directly define them with the service

Comment: It is a solution to fix the problem. But the real problem was that this way of writing is not wrong, it was typescript that complained. So it was not really an answer to my question...

Answer (score -1):

No need of initialise services in constructor() now instead of that you can use inject(ServicesName)

for example like this: private Hservice = inject(HouseService);